# what happen while debugging my source code if power is off

Tags: c

while debugging my source code my pc pointing inside  the ISR function.so now  what happens if power is off? please tell me answer the pc start at what location if power will come again?

Comment: What would have happened if while posting this question the power would have gone off?!

Comment: Please provide a little more context.

Comment: ISR as in *Interrupt Service Routines*?

Answer (score 3):

When the computer restarts the PC will be reset to its initial value which points at the entrance of the BIOS. The exact value depends on the platform. Your ISR and the contents of memory will also be gone.